Different error queues for same consumer determined runtime
When MassTransit encounter an exception the default logic is to send it to an error queue which is named [queue-name]_error. I know that this can be changed and of the different settings to ignore and handle errors and set up different retries/redeliveries.
Is there a possbility to dynamically, prefereably at runtime, different error queues based on exception thrown?
I have tinkered a bit with different middlewares on ConsumeContext, ConsumeContext and ExceptionReceivedContext and have had some luck with ConsumeContext to achieve what I want to do but the code gets a bit messy so I was wondering if there is some sort of built in support for this logic.
Say you have an queue BookTicket (which by default messages where there are exceptions thrown would end up in BookTicket_error) and for IOException could direct the message to BookTicket_io_error and SqlException would go to BookTicket_sql_error and all others in the default error queue.
The reason is that we have defined a set of exceptions to be easily re-processed and want to shovel them back from one queue and have other exceptions (format of messages which cannot be easily re-processed) in another queue which will have to be more manually handled.
We are using the latest version of MassTransit and .net 8. There are no legacy considerations.
